# Play framework redirect to custom schemes

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to redirect from my play framework server to a custom url scheme like `file`, but its not working

Server is running on 9000 and my endpoint takes `redirect_uri` param.
Ex: http://localhost:9000/redirect?redirect_uri=file:///test

The browser is not redirected to if the url scheme is not `http` or `https`

route:

```
GET  /redirect  MyController.testRedirect(redirect_uri:String)
```

Controller:

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.Logger

object MyController extends Controller {

  def testRedirect(redirect_uri: String) = Action {
    Logger.info(s"Opening: $redirect_uri")
    Redirect(redirect_uri)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem of Play (or any other web framework for that matter). It is just how the browser is expected to work.

There are special restrictions applied on browsers when protocols like `file:` are involved. Of course you could argue that there shouldn't be any problem when the file is local but the general idea is to be on the safe side so this restriction is kind of global.

The are some pseudo-protocols like `javascript:` and `data:` which are permitted but nothing else should be allowed (except `http:` and `https:` of course).

You can read a bit more here:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/browsersec/wikis/Part2.wiki#Redirection_restrictions

---

If you want to return some file to your visitor you can just stream the data / provide a download option. Anything else won't work and should make you rethink your use case.